# I want to let the user to submit form only for once and after he can update it

Tags: php, mysql, row

I am working on a project where it got two tables; users table and movie table

i have code which submits the form related to movie info after user has logged in but what i want to do is insert that data only for once into the table and after insertion user can update it as he likes.

I have written code for insertion as you know every time i submit form it inserts a new row with data and i want only one row to be inserted and after that user can update it.

My code for insertion is as follows

```
if (isset($_POST['an-submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['anfav'])) {
        $errors['anfav'] = 'Favourite required';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['anrank'])) {
        $errors['anrank'] = 'Rank required';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['anrewatched'])) {
        $errors['anrewatched'] = 'Rewatched required';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['anstatus'])) {
        $errors['anstatus'] = 'Status required';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['anrecommend'])) {
        $errors['anrecommend'] = 'Recommend required';
    }

    $anfav = $_POST['anfav'];
    $anrank = $_POST['anrank'];
    $anrewatched = $_POST['anrewatched'];
    $anstatus = $_POST['anstatus'];
    $anrecommend = $_POST['anrecommend'];
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];

    // Select id from users and insert into movie
    if (count($errors) === 0) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO anime SET movie_fav=?, movie_rank=?, movie_rewatch=?, movie_status=?, movie_rec=?, id =?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('siissi', $anfav, $anrank, $anrewatched, $anstatus, $anrecommend, $id);
        $result = $stmt->execute();

        if ($result) {
            $movie_id = $stmt->insert_id;
            $stmt->close();

            $_SESSION['movieid'] = $movie_id;   
            $_SESSION['anfav'] = $anfav;
            $_SESSION['anrank'] = $anrank;
            $_SESSION['anrewatched'] = $anrewatched;
            $_SESSION['anstatus'] = $anstatus;
            $_SESSION['anrecommend'] = $anrecommend;
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Details have been submitted successfully!';
            $_SESSION['type'] = 'alert-success';
            header('location: movieinfo.php');
        } else {
            $_SESSION['error_msg'] = "Database error: Could not update details";
        }
    }
}
```

How can i make form submitted only for once and latter make it updatable 
Can anyone help me with this

Thank you

Comment: the normal way: if you fill the form (html-form) create a hidden field with "id" as Name and the Primary-key ($movie_id) as value. If there is no record (new record) the id is "0". In the script you can check if the id is !=0 (update) or "0" (insert)

Comment: Can also use [INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) so that if a unique key violation occurs then it becomes an update. I didn't follow if the user_id was unique or (user_id,movie_id). Both work however.

Comment: In users table id is primary key and in movie table id is foreign key and movieid is primary key.

Comment: And am sorry i forgot to mention but am using select tags in my form

Comment: It sounds like what you need may be two separate pages. 1 that allows for the unique insert, and the other for updating a sql line. Thankfully as stated in a prior comment so long as you have a unique id tag in your database you can then call the row in sql based on the ID and echo in the values to your update form.

Comment: @Alex Carlson Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to movieinfo.php with last inserted id like  `header('location: movieinfo.php?movie_id='.$movie_id);` and no need to store data of all fields in session. In movieinfo.php you can fetch details of  movie_id from respective table and display it in the HTML form for update.

For example:

```
if (isset($_POST['an-submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['anfav'])) {
        $errors['anfav'] = 'Favourite required';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['anrank'])) {
        $errors['anrank'] = 'Rank required';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['anrewatched'])) {
        $errors['anrewatched'] = 'Rewatched required';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['anstatus'])) {
        $errors['anstatus'] = 'Status required';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['anrecommend'])) {
        $errors['anrecommend'] = 'Recommend required';
    }

    $anfav = $_POST['anfav'];
    $anrank = $_POST['anrank'];
    $anrewatched = $_POST['anrewatched'];
    $anstatus = $_POST['anstatus'];
    $anrecommend = $_POST['anrecommend'];
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];

    // Select id from users and insert into movie
    if (count($errors) === 0) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO anime SET movie_fav=?, movie_rank=?, movie_rewatch=?, movie_status=?, movie_rec=?, id =?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('siissi', $anfav, $anrank, $anrewatched, $anstatus, $anrecommend, $id);
        $result = $stmt->execute();

        if ($result) {
            $movie_id = $stmt->insert_id;
            $stmt->close();

            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Details have been submitted successfully!';
            $_SESSION['type'] = 'alert-success';
            header('location: movieinfo.php?movie_id='.$movie_id);
        } else {
            $_SESSION['error_msg'] = "Database error: Could not update details";
$_SESSION['type'] = 'alert-error';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your response . I have tried making changes according to your suggestions but i still get info inserted into new row each time i submit form

Comment: @karthik, please share movieinfo.php script.

Comment: actually i have tried creating two forms according to  Alex Carsons suggestion and it worked out. Anyway thank you for your help